# CoordinatorLayout with hideable fragment on bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've got a CoordinatorLayout with an AppBarLayout and a collapsible TabLayout. I've got a ViewPager for my content. This is the working hierarchy so far:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar />
        <TabLayout />
    </AppBarLayout>
    <ViewPager />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now I want to have a Fragment at the bottom which I can hide. When the bottom fragment is hidden the ViewPager should take all available space. When the bottom fragment is visible no parts of the ViewPager should be obfuscated.

This is the first try:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar />
        <TabLayout />
    </AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:elevation="@dimen/action_bar_elevation"/>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Using this layout, the bottom part of my ViewPager is obfuscated when the frame layout is visible. Giving the ViewPager a bottom margin with the FrameLayouts height I always have a blank space at the bottom even if the FrameLayout is gone.

I tried to wrap the ViewPager and the FrameLayout in a LinearLayout but then the top part of the ViewPager is behind the AppBar when the FrameLayout for the fragment is visible.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your issue, but why don't you try this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar />
        <TabLayout />
    </AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:elevation="@dimen/action_bar_elevation"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

`ViewPager's` `layout_width` and `layout_weight` are really important, so copy those exact values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already tried using LinearLayout and layout_weight. That's what I meant in the last part of my question. With this approach the ViewPager and the FrameLayout don't overlap and the ViewPager is aligned with the bottom of the screen when the FrameLayout is gone. The problem now is that the top portion of my ViewPager is obscured by the AppBar no matter if the FrameLayout is gone or visible.

Comment: did you try moving `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: just for the purpose of seeing if this helps with AppBar overlapping your layout?

Comment: I think we're getting close. The thing now is that the FrameLayout only appears when I'm scrolling down and dissappears when scrolling up similar to the collapsible toolbar. That's cool but just not the right behaviour for this app. No overlapping issues now.

Comment: Can you move the layout_behavior to the LinearLayout in your answer? I will accept it then.

Comment: Sure thing, my friend :)